# 'Unexpected echo' PHP error message - outputting php variable in html input 'value' field

Tags: php, html, mysql

I keep on receiving this error message when running the PHP code below ::

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\informationdb\item.php on line 93"

I am trying to output dynamic PHP variables in a static html table using a `foreach` loop. By any chance, can anyone spot where the error lies?

My code is as follows::

```
<table>
<form action='', method="POST"> 

                            <?php 
                            foreach($libitem["libraries"] as $library) { 
                                foreach($libitem["libraryitemids"] as $libraryitemid) { 
                                    foreach($libitem["sectionnames"] as $sectionName) { 
                                        foreach($libitem["sectionnumbers"] as $sectionNumber) {
                                            echo "<tr><td id='radiocell'><input type='radio' name='libraryitemid' id='radio' value='" . $libraryitemid . "'></td><td>" . echo $library . "</td><td>" . echo $sectionName . "</td><td>" . echo $sectionNumber . "</td><td class='available'>Available</td></tr>";                                    
                                        } 
                                    } 
                                } 
                            } 

                            ?>


                        </table>
```

Comment: P.s. just in case anyone is wondering, line 93 is the line that the 'echo' statement is on :)

Comment: One echo is enough when concatenating. Also you may consider re-writing those foreaches into something less....performance loss-y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are concatenating a string, you use dots, but no `echo`, also see the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php):

```
echo "<tr><td id='radiocell'><input type='radio' name='libraryitemid' id='radio' value='" . $libraryitemid . "'></td><td>"
    . echo $library . "</td><td>"
    . echo $sectionName . "</td><td>"
    . echo $sectionNumber . "</td><td class='available'>Available</td></tr>";
```

should be:

```
echo "<tr><td id='radiocell'><input type='radio' name='libraryitemid' id='radio' value='" . $libraryitemid . "'></td><td>"
    . $library . "</td><td>"
    . $sectionName . "</td><td>"
    . $sectionNumber . "</td><td class='available'>Available</td></tr>";
```

Comment: Thanks @jeroen , you're a star! All the answers here were right, btw.

Comment: @RobertYoung I imagine, it is one of the basic things of string concatenation :-)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `echo` here

```
 . echo $library . "</td><td>" . echo $sectionName . "</td><td>" . echo $sectionNumber . "
```

There is need only first echo. 
For concatenation isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `echo` from inside the string.

For example, 
`" . $libraryitemid . "'></td><td>" . echo $library . "</td><td>" . echo $sectionName .`
shoule be
`" . $libraryitemid . "'></td><td>" . $library . "</td><td>" . $sectionName . "<`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo "<tr><td id='radiocell'><input type='radio' name='libraryitemid' id='radio' value='" . $libraryitemid . "'></td><td>" . $library . "</td><td>" . $sectionName . "</td><td>" . $sectionNumber . "</td><td class='available'>Available</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using echo in the echo which is an error .
remove this line .

```
echo "<tr><td id='radiocell'><input type='radio' name='libraryitemid' id='radio' value='" . $libraryitemid . "'></td><td>" . echo $library . "</td><td>" . echo $sectionName . "</td><td>" . echo $sectionNumber . "</td><td class='available'>Available</td></tr>";
```

you should use this

```
<table>
<form action='', method="POST"> 

                            <?php 
                            foreach($libitem["libraries"] as $library) { 
                                foreach($libitem["libraryitemids"] as $libraryitemid) { 
                                    foreach($libitem["sectionnames"] as $sectionName) { 
                                        foreach($libitem["sectionnumbers"] as $sectionNumber) {
                                            echo "<tr><td id='radiocell'><input type='radio' name='libraryitemid' id='radio' value='" . $libraryitemid . "'></td><td>" .  $library . "</td><td>" .  $sectionName . "</td><td>" . $sectionNumber . "</td><td class='available'>Available</td></tr>";                                    
                                        } 
                                    } 
                                } 
                            } 

                            ?>


                        </table>
```